# MySql View and paging is causing full table scans

Tags: mysql, paging, sql-view, full-table-scan

During our MySQL performance review we saw that we had a few full-table scans in our code. 
We created a view which spans different tables which are Master - detail records. For example, sales and saleslines.

On this master detail record we have the requirement to add paging. So we must be able to fetch the first 10 Sales (and their according sales lines). But also to fetch the first 10 sales which have a salesline where 1 unit-price is higher than 10$.

So we created a view, in this scenario vw_sales, which joins the sale and sale-lines and we are able to meet those requirements.

The Create Tables can be viewed here

```
CREATE TABLE `sale_test` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `amount` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL,
  `created_on` datetime NOT NULL,
  `tenant_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `version` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  `culture` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_sale_on_tenant` (`tenant_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;


CREATE TABLE `sales_line_test` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sale_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `quantity` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `unit_price` decimal(20,2) NOT NULL,
  `offer_product_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `product_id` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tenant_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `version` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_sales_line_on_sale` (`sale_id`),
  KEY `fk_sales_line_on_product` (`offer_product_id`),
  KEY `fk_sales_line_on_tenant` (`tenant_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

The view is created as here

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
    ALGORITHM = MERGE 
    DEFINER = `root`@`localhost` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `vw_sales` AS
    SELECT 
        `sale_test`.`id` AS `id`,
        `sale_test`.`amount` AS `amount`,
        `sale_test`.`created_on` AS `createdon`,
        `sale_test`.`tenant_id` AS `tenantid`,
        `sales_line_test`.`id` AS `saleslineid`,        
        `sales_line_test`.`quantity` AS `quantity`,
        `sales_line_test`.`unit_price` AS `unitprice`
    FROM
        `sale_test` FORCE INDEX (`fk_sale_on_tenant`)     
        INNER JOIN `sales_line_test` `sales_line_test` ON (`sales_line_test`.`sale_id` = `sale_test`.`id`);
```

We added the paging like  below

```
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE
        WHEN @previous = id THEN @rank
        WHEN @previous:=id THEN @rank:=@rank + 1
    END AS rank
FROM
    vw_sales,
    (SELECT @previous:=0) previous,
    (SELECT @rank:=- 1) rank
WHERE
    id = 26
ORDER BY id ASC
```

The result with the explain command looks like this

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+------------------+
| id | select_type |      table      | partitions |  type  |     possible_keys     |          key          | key_len |              ref              | rows | filtered |      Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>      | NULL       | system | NULL                  | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL                          | 1    | 100.00   | "Using filesort" |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived3>      | NULL       | system | NULL                  | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL                          | 1    | 100.00   | NULL             |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived4>      | NULL       | ref    | <auto_key0>           | <auto_key0>           | 8       | const                         | 1    | 100.00   | "Using where"    |
|  4 | DERIVED     | sale_test       | NULL       | ALL    | NULL                  | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL                          | 1    | 100.00   | NULL             |
|  4 | DERIVED     | sales_line_test | NULL       | ref    | fk_sales_line_on_sale | fk_sales_line_on_sale | 8       | order_management.sale_test.id | 1    | 100.00   | NULL             |
|  3 | DERIVED     | NULL            | NULL       | NULL   | NULL                  | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL                          | NULL | NULL     | "No tables used" |
|  2 | DERIVED     | NULL            | NULL       | NULL   | NULL                  | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL                          | NULL | NULL     | "No tables used" |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+------------------+
```

However we see that due to a limitation in MySql (materialized views) we are causing some full-table scans - table sale_test. (ref. [How do I get MySQL to use an INDEX for view query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944946/how-do-i-get-mysql-to-use-an-index-for-view-query?answertab=active#tab-top) , [Does MySQL view always do full table scan?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/637328/does-mysql-view-always-do-full-table-scan) )

Creating a covering index accross tables doesn't seem to be possible so this options is not possible as well.

We already added the force index inside the view as well to hint the correct index but this doesn't resolve the issue.

How is this being resolved in a descent way? Is creating a temporary table not causing a lot of overhead? 
This seems so simple but the paging requirements is making it very hard. 
We are working with mysql 5.7 (AWS RDS) so the window functions added in mysql 8.0 are not an option for us.

FYI: Without the view we see that the index is being used

Query:

```
SELECT 
    `sale_test`.`id` AS `id`,
    `sale_test`.`amount` AS `amount`,
    `sale_test`.`created_on` AS `createdon`,
    `sale_test`.`tenant_id` AS `tenantid`,
    `sales_line_test`.`id` AS `saleslineid`,
    `sales_line_test`.`quantity` AS `quantity`,
    `sales_line_test`.`unit_price` AS `unitprice`,
    CASE
        WHEN @previous = `sale_test`.`id` THEN @rank
        WHEN @previous:= `sale_test`.`id` THEN @rank:=@rank + 1
    END AS rank
FROM
    `sale_test` FORCE INDEX (FK_SALE_ON_TENANT)
        INNER JOIN
    `sales_line_test` `sales_line_test` ON (`sales_line_test`.`sale_id` = `sale_test`.`id`),
    (SELECT @previous:=0) previous,
    (SELECT @rank:=- 1) rank
WHERE
    `sale_test`.`tenant_id` = 26
```

Result

```
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+------------------+
| id | select_type |      table      | partitions |  type  |     possible_keys     |          key          | key_len |              ref              | rows | filtered |      Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>      | NULL       | system | NULL                  | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL                          | 1    | 100.00   | NULL             |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived3>      | NULL       | system | NULL                  | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL                          | 1    | 100.00   | NULL             |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | sale_test       | NULL       | ref    | fk_sale_on_tenant     | fk_sale_on_tenant     | 8       | const                         | 1    | 100.00   | NULL             |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | sales_line_test | NULL       | ref    | fk_sales_line_on_sale | fk_sales_line_on_sale | 8       | order_management.sale_test.id | 1    | 100.00   | NULL             |
|  3 | DERIVED     | NULL            | NULL       | NULL   | NULL                  | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL                          | NULL | NULL     | "No tables used" |
|  2 | DERIVED     | NULL            | NULL       | NULL   | NULL                  | NULL                  | NULL    | NULL                          | NULL | NULL     | "No tables used" |
+----+-------------+-----------------+------------+--------+-----------------------+-----------------------+---------+-------------------------------+------+----------+------------------+
```

Comment: If you create a VIEW with MERGE algorithm.. MySQL can optimize queries on VIEWS better.. see source https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-algorithms.html

Comment: "So we created a view, in this scenario vw_sales, which joins the sale and sale-lines and we are able to meet those requirements. " You should really include the SQL code behide the view and the tables.. Also add example data on sql-fiddle.com or df-fiddle.com.. Also include expected output as a ascii data table (text formatted).. Al this is required read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask section  "Help others reproduce the problem"

Comment: @raymondNijland : I have updated this post so all the information is now available I think. Can you take a look ?

Comment: I have a feeling MySQL optimizer can´t use ALGORITHM = MERGE because off the MySQL´s user variables in the query take a look into this.. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vvAQJitjEeA8zypBta2uHW/0 ...`SHOW WARNINGS` shows you how the MySQL optimizer "handles" the SQL query.. You see that the first query is use the SQL code behide the VIEW. The second is not.. The 3th query indeed confirms it the rewrite does not happen when a MySQL user variable are in the query..

Comment: @raymondnijland do you have a hint how we could resolve this? Or should we just skip the view...

Comment: @raymondNijland : you are correct due to the user variables, the merge strategy can not be used (ref. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-algorithms.html)

Comment: "do you have a hint how we could resolve this?" Upgrade to MySQL 8.0? Which support windows functions like ROW_NUMBER and RANK which your are simulating with that use off MySQL's user variables.